# How do I get cpu_times of process run with psutil.Popen after it is finished but before it is terminated

Tags: python, subprocess, psutil

I would like to use the `cpu_times()` method of a `psutil.Popen` object to find the cumulative values **after it has finished**. I first tried the following:

```py
p = psutil.Popen("stress --cpu 3 -v -t 15", shell=True)
p.wait()
cpuTimes = p.cpu_times()
```

However, this results in a `NoSuchProcess` exception because `wait()` doesn't return until the process is terminated. I next tried putting the call to `cpu_times()` **before** the call to `wait()`:

```py
p = psutil.Popen("stress --cpu 3 -v -t 15", shell=True)
cpuTimes = p.cpu_times()
p.wait()
```

However, this yields a response of all zeros. I presume this is because it gets called immediately after the process starts. So, I **added a call to `time.sleep()`** that would just outlast the process:

```py
p = psutil.Popen("stress --cpu 3 -v -t 15", shell=True)
time.sleep(15.) # b/c -t 15 in subprocess means it will take 15 seconds
cpuTimes = p.cpu_times()
p.wait()
```

This actually yields the expected value of 45 seconds (3 CPUs at 100% utilization for 15 seconds).

For a general process, however, I will not know how long it will take to finish. I would like to avoid adding an arbitrarily large sleep time just to make sure the process has finished before I make my query.

Is there a way to know that the process is done without calling `wait()` or other such methods upon whose return the process has terminated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I found a solution. It was actually pretty simple, so I probably should have thought of it before posting my question, but I guess that's the way these things sometimes go.

```py
p = psutil.Popen("stress --cpu 3 -v -t 15", shell=True)
cpuTimes = p.cpu_times()
while True:
    time.sleep(1e-4)
    cpuTimes = p.cpu_times()  # Make sure to do this before the call to poll()
    retCode = p.poll()
    if retCode is not None:
        break
```

Here, I have added a loop after starting the subprocess that contains calls to the 
`cpu_times()` and `poll()` methods for the process.

The `poll()` method is a non-blocking way to check whether the subprocess has finished. By calling `cpu_times()` right before the call to `poll()`, a minuscule amount of time will have passed, so we can, for all intents and purposes, consider the last call to `cpu_times()` to yield an accurate result.

Note that we would get an exception when calling `cpu_times()` after `poll()` if the process has finished. This is another reason to put the call to `cpu_times()` before the call to `poll()`.

The argument to the `sleep()` method is not super important but does influence how much time will elapse after the subprocess finishes and before the loop will terminate. You could probably also add some sort of generous timeout to guard against an infinite loop if the subprocess never finishes.

Comment: Thank you! This needs to pulled into psutil's docs. This is the best example for psutil.Popen

Comment: Thank you, @chaostheory. I am glad you found it helpful.

Comment: Won't this cause a performance issue, polling 10,000 times per second?

Comment: @ElliottB, you are probably correct. I imagine it could cause some non-negligible performance issue. As mentioned above, I believe the argument to `sleep()` will mostly serve to control how much time elapses after the process terminates. Thus, one could pick a larger value than I have, causing one to `poll()` less often if that is a concern.